# dynamic variable names using Ruby's instance_variable_set

Tags: ruby, dynamic, instance-variables

I'm trying to create a set of instances that have different instance names using instance_variable_set to change the instance name and I can't seem to get it to
work.

```
 for i in 0..3 do
   username_str   = String.new
   username_str   = 'user_' + i.to_s

   username_new   = User.new
   username_new.instance_variable_set("@#{WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE?}", username_str)

   username_new = User.create(:username => username_str)

 end
```

The part I can't figure out is what do I put in the first field of instance_variable_set where I have "WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE?"?

Comment: This isn't an answer to what you're asking, but it's worth pointing out since it's surely a mistake: You're setting `username_new` to a User instance, setting an instance variable on that object, then throwing the object away and setting it to a new object that you get from `User.create`.

Comment: @Chuck:  What I am trying to do is create a bunch of Users with different usernames.  The worry I had was that I didn't think I could reuse the username_new variable each time through the loop.  Maybe I am wrong about that, although I've tried removing the line with instance_variable_set, and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance variables might be the wrong tool for the job.  If all you want to do is create three users, then:

```
3.times do |i|
  User.create(:username => "user_#{i}")
end
```

If you need to retain the User objects for later use, then you can use an array:

```
@users = 3.times.map do |i|
  User.create(:username => "user_#{i}")
end
```

after which `@users[0]` will retrieve the first instance of User, `@users[1]` the second, &c.

Comment: Yup, this is all I needed.  I actually had this, but because there was a bug in the parameters I was using for User.create(params), the users weren't getting created.  So I came across instance_variable_set, thinking that would fix the problem, when in reality there was just a bug in my code :-)  Thanks again!

Comment: @james Testa, You're welcome!  By the way, if you use `create!` instead of `create`, you'll get a nice exception if it doesn't get created.

Answer (score 0):

You would put a string containing the name of the instance variable you want to set. Alternatively, if you do not have such a string, you could just skip the string interpolation and write the name of the instance variable in there yourself.

Comment: Wouldn't the string with the name of the instance variable I want to set be "username_new"?  I tried putting "username_new" there and I got an error.

Comment: @James Testa: No, the variable `username_new` references an instance of User, not a String. The error you got was probably along the lines of "This is not a valid name for an instance variable." Whatever instance variable in User represents the name is what you'd want to use there.

Comment: Boy, I'm still confused.  What I am trying to do is create a bunch of users with different user names using a for loop.  Is username_new an instance variable?  Or in this case would "username" be an instance variable?